# Javascript - Jquery Pagination Ajax for wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have tried to make a very simple script for loading pages in wordpress -

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 // ajax pagination
 jQuery('.navigation a').live('click', function(){ // wp pagination link on default theme
 var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 // #content is the content wrapper
 jQuery('#content').append('<div><h2>Loading...</h2></div>');
 // .entry is a single post wrapper
jQuery('#content').append(link+'.entry')
    });
}); // end ready function
</script>
```

tried also :

```
jQuery('#content').load(link+'.entry')
```

and

```
//tried also .load.ajax and prepend.ajax
 jQuery('#content').prepend.ajax({
      url: link,
      });
```

somehow they all work the same, I do see a "loading" div, but then the page gets refreshed with the new posts - I can not seem to append it to the end , or to the div that I need..

Comment: Do you have separate template to handle the ajax load ?? You cannot directly load and append new pages with normal template. The ajax template shouldn't have header / sidebar / footer and other layout elements.

Comment: yes , I do have a special template , but it had a header call. stupid me . I will ty to remove, and in the meantie you can post it as an answer for me to accept .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt was correct but if you're targetting an element within the page you're requesting there needs to be a space between the URL and the selector, so instead of this:

```
jQuery('#content').load(link + '.entry');
```

Do this:

```
jQuery('#content').load(link + ' .entry');
```

That will grab the element `.entry` and asynchronously load it into `#content`.